# Preload inApp Browser in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, preload, inappbrowser

I have a page that is loading slowly in the inApp browser on phonegap? Is there a way to preload a page for the inApp browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'hidden=yes');
ref.show();
```

You can control the view of inAppBrowser. So you can load the link before and show(call into user's view) anytime. Untill you call `ref.show()` it won't be visible if you make `hidden=yes`.